# Xamarin: Detect network/host reachability

Tags: ios, xamarin, connectivity

I'm experimenting with "Reachability" in Xmarin, using the `Reachability` class ([sample here](http://developer.xamarin.com/samples/ReachabilitySample/)), but I cannot get the "IsHostReachable" feature to work.

I do realize that the `Reachability` class utilizes the `NetworkReachability` class but no matter which class I use the `TryGetFlags()` method always passes back the `NetworkReachabilityFlags` argument with a zero (0) value.

I started out using the `Reachability` class' method but while debugging I saw that the problem seems to originate in `NetworkReachability`. I tried the following code just to make sure:

```
using (var r = new NetworkReachability(host))
{
    NetworkReachabilityFlags flags;
    if (r.TryGetFlags(out flags)) // <-- flags is always 0 (zero)
        return (flags & NetworkReachabilityFlags.Reachable) == NetworkReachabilityFlags.Reachable;
    return false;
}
```

Like I said the `flags` variable is passed back with a zero (0) value, regardless of the device's current connection status. The host I'm testing against is a intranet web app that is only available when I'm on my company's WIFI. I have tested debuging the iPhone while connected and double checked by simply trying to browse to the host in Safari, which works.

The API is poorly documented but I'm suspecting I might need to initialize the `NetworkReachability` class somehow.

Any ideas?

Comment: I also have experienced flags = 0 response and can't seem to figure out the problem. I have filed a bug with details here https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=28713 and you can contribute if you think you have relevant information. Xamarin pages on SystemConfiguration seem to have vanished from their previous locations and even the current links in the Api reference are not working